# Converting multipe TypeScript files into into individual JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp

Not sure if this has been answered before so applogies. I am working on a project where I have two typescript files List.ts and TelephoneNumbers.ts. What I want to do is to transpile the files into List.js and TelephoneNumbers.js and then minify them. I do **not** want is the files to be transpiled into **one** file.

Additional information:

1. I am using gulp
2. The development environment is WebStorm on Windows 10

**Edit**

So how do I do this? If gulp is not a viable option then what tooling should I use?

This is the relevant method in my gulp.js

```js
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');

function typescriptPreProcessor(fileName) {
    fileName = fileName.replaceAll(/\.ts$/gi, '.js');

    let tsProject = ts.createProject('Source/Scripts/tsconfig.json')
    tsProject.src().pipe(tsProject()).js.pipe(gulp.dest(fileName));

    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Great, modern tooling should perform this job pretty easily. Gulp is basically dead, so many consider finding something else. You didn't specify a question though.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really for announcing your work goals. If there's a question here, a good format would be: My goal is X, I tried Y, I got stuck at Z. Share details, and if you see error messages copy them verbatim. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Uhm, if you just run `tsc` in the terminal without specifying a single output file, you will get separate `.js` files...

Comment: @Evert A lot of people don't want to constantly move the tooling to a new platform and quite often it is not possible due to the time involved in migrating the code, rewriting the scripts. Also I thought the question is implicit in what I had written.

Comment: @GrahamHarris sure, not telling you what to do; but just putting it out there as general advice because you will find it increasingly hard to get answers to your questions. What you're trying to do is easy with a bash script which has been relevant for many decades. No idea with gulp.